# Docker - Nginx not enabling custom configuration

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm trying to deploy a Flask application using uWSGI and Nginx as a reverse proxy.

They're connected through a unix socket (at least that's the idea).

So, this is my flask application:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
    def root():
        return "Hello, world!"

    return app
```

And this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx-python

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./demoapp.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/demoapp.conf

EXPOSE 9090

CMD uwsgi --ini demoapp.ini
```

Where nginx-python is a custom image I created, it (obviously) has nginx and python ready to go.

And this is my demoapp.ini for uWSGI:

```
[uwsgi]
module = app:create_app()

master = true
processes = 2

socket = demoapp.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

**And** finally, this is my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 9090;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/app/demoapp.sock
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm running the image:

> $ docker container run -it -p 7777:9090 -p 6666:80 demoapp

As you can see I'm mapping two ports.
`7777` should redirect to `9090` which is the one that Nginx uses to communicate with uWSGI through unix socket.

And `6666` to `80` which is the default server for Nginx (the one that loads the Nginx welcome page).

Why am I mentioning that? Because it turns out that when I navigate to:

> http://localhost:7777/

It says that the page can't be reached.

**BUT** when I navigate to:

> http://localhost:6666/

It renders the Nginx welcome page perfectly fine.

And just as a side note, I know that I could use Docker Compose and separate the Flask app into its own container and the Nginx into another container.

I'm doing it like this just as a self-assigned practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `demoapp.ini` you have

```
socket = demoapp.sock
```

Which doesn't match the path in the nginx config. I always use a complete path in my projects, and I put the `.sock` files in `/tmp/`

You're also doing something that I haven't seen before, so if fixing the above doesn't work, try changing

```
[uwsgi]
module = app:create_app()
```

to

```
[uwsgi]
module = app:app
```

and add

```
app = create_app()
```

to the bottom of `app.py`.